# How to map spark DataFrame row values to columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to map values in rows to columns in another dataframe.

I have the following DataFrame, the values in "id" are known to be unique:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("a", 1),("b",2))).toDF("id","number")
```

And:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("jane",10),("John",12))).toDF("mcid", "age")
```

And I wish to produce a DataFrame with the schema:

```
| mcid | age | a | b |
```

Comment: Please be a little more clear about your task. Do you want to join both DataFrames? What is your expected result for the example shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are try to do, but assuming you have this:

```
val df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("a", 1),("b",2))).toDF("id","number")
val df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("jane",10),("John",12))).toDF("mcid", "age")
```

This will get you a `DataFrame` with the schema you are looking for:

```
df2.join(df1).groupBy($"mcid", $"age").pivot("id").sum("number")
```

Comment: Thank you that answers my question.